# Powershell New Service Failing To Start or Manually Run: Error 1053

Tags: windows, powershell, service, windows-server

I created a new service in Powershell (as administrator) PSVersion 5.1.17763.1007.  The new service exists, but fails to run in either Powershell or Services.

In Powershell:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> `Get-Service ztest|Start-Service`
>
> Start-Service : Service 'ztest (zTest)' cannot be started due to the
> following error: Cannot start service zTest on  computer '.'. At
> line:1 char:19
> + Get-Service ztest|Start-Service
> \                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~     + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController)
> [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId
> :
> CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

In Services:
I receive a 1053 error *The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.*

What Has Been Done:
I used a powershell script that I have converted to a .exe file via Win-PS2Exe.  When I run the .exe file, the program works as expected.

Creating New Service:
`New-Service -Name zTest1 -BinaryPathName $filepath -DisplayName zTest1 -Description $description -StartupType Automatic -Credential $cred`

I have changed Timeout settings in Regedit, added both files and folders to trusted locations, granted ownership and full access to the service account for .exe files and folders, I have written PS Scripts and converted it to a .exe (Win-PS2Exe) `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file 'C:\users\...\desktop\RunTESTNoCommentsReview.exe'`

About the .exe file:
The .exe file does not end. It is in an infinite while loop pausing 1 minute at a time.

I have read people saying potential issues with the name not being what it is expected to be in Windows Service Manager, but I couldn't find any additional documentation past their comments.

My Machine:
I am currently running Windows Server 2019 Standard that is up to date.

I am unsure if I am supposed to register the service somewhere, or what else I could be missing.

Comment: An NT service does not run like a regular program. There are other APIs that are needed and certainly converting a script to EXE would not do that.

Comment: If you've got a generic non-"services aware" ```*.exe``` that you want to run as a service you can use a service host like NSSM (https://nssm.cc/commands) as the actual service exe, and configure that to run your program as a child process. NSSM will handle "start" and "stop" commands for the service and launch or terminate your application as appropriate. I've not used it recently, but it used to work like a charm way back when I last had to...

Comment: How to write Windows Services in PowerShell is fully documented by MIcrosoft here: [Writing Windows Services in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/may/windows-powershell-writing-windows-services-in-powershell#:~:text=%20To%20create%20your%20own%20service%2C%20just%20do,Currently%2C%20the%20while%20%28%24true%29%20block%20just...%20More%20)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment.

You are not showing any of your code that you say is being used as your service.

There are [many examples of how to do this all over the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27create%20a%20powershell%20service%27&t=h_&ia=web).

For [Example](https://www.yaplex.com/blog/create-a-windows-service-using-powershell):

```
$serviceName = "MyService"

if (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    $serviceToRemove = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='$serviceName'"
    $serviceToRemove.delete()
    "service removed"
}
else
{
    "service does not exists"
}

"installing service"

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (".\MYUser", $secpasswd)
$binaryPath = "c:\servicebinaries\MyService.exe"
New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $mycreds

"installation completed"
```

So, without [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) stuff like the above, you force us to assume.